# Map foreign key as well as reference in NHibernate without creating extra column

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I want to map **both** the foreign key as a POCO property **and** the navigation property. IE in the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691366/fluent-nhibernate-how-to-map-a-foreign-key-column-in-the-mapping-class) , the answer substitutes the foreign key

```
 public virtual int SongArtistID { get; set; }
```

I want to keep that key in the mapping. I have tried so far:

```
Map(x => x.ParentID);
References(x => x.Parent).Column("ParentID");

Map(x => x.ParentID);
References(x => x.Parent, "ParentID");
```

and many other combinations using the fluent mapper but I can't get it working. The problem is that the `References()` directive always creates an extra column.

Answer (score 4):

You don't map the same relationship twice in NHibernate.

It's just:

```
References(x => x.Parent, "ParentID")
```

And then you use this to get the FK value:

```
var parentId = obj.Parent.Id;
```

Or this to assign it:

```
obj.Parent = session.Load<TheClassOfTheParent>(parentId);
```

And none of those statements will result in a db call.

Comment: I don't want to map a relationship twice, I just want to access the property as a simple (for example int) property without any knowledge of ORM, session, etc, just data model

Comment: Well, it won't work. NHibernate is oriented towards working with an object model based on relationships, not a DB model based on foreign keys.

Comment: Actually, it works, problem wasnt in `Reference()` see my reply

Comment: Thank you for the reply and attention however!

Comment: I would disagree with @DiegoMijelshon, see my answer here  http://stackoverflow.com/a/37436232/173073

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out, mapping the way I showed was perfectly fine. The problem with the extra field was created by the other side of the relationship. What I had was:

```
class ParentMap

        HasMany(x => x.Children)
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All();

class ChildMap

        Map(x => x.ParentID);
        References(x => x.Parent).Column("ParentID");
```

I had to specify the column on the `HasMany()` of the parent instead of actually on the `Reference()` of the child, like so:

```
class ParentMap

        HasMany(x => x.Children)
            .KeyColumn("ParentID") // Problem without this!
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All();
```